# Overfull \vbox with a document containing no images

Tags: debugging

[I updated the text so it includes a Overfull \vbox of 5.37814pt now]

My document has more like this, but this is an example of a overfull \vbox (I hope I got it right)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{polyglossia}



\makeatletter
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@
  \vskip 3mm}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\footnoteB}[2][*]
{\bgroup
  \edef\thempfn{$#1$}%
  \footnote[0]{#2}%
\egroup}

%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}

x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\dobët e në rrezik të madh për vete. Rusët ndodheshin tepër larg e, veç kësaj, edhe ata kishin telashet e tyre. Por cili katolik do të ngarendte në ndihmë të një populli besëpak e përçarës? Duke menduar kësisoj, perandori Gjoni V iu nënshtrua personalisht papës në Itali, më 1369; por ai, si i kujdesshëm që ishte, nuk pranoi të merrte përsipër asnjë detyrim në lidhje me shtetasit e vet, ndonëse shpresonte më kot se do t’i bindte të ndiqnin shembullin e tij\footnote{Halečki, \emph{Un Empereur de Byzance à Rome}, f. 205, dhe, në mënyrë të veçantë, Charanis, \emph{The strife among the Palaeologi and the Ottoman Turks}, në «Byzantion», XVI, I, ff. 287-293.}.

As Mihali VIII dhe as Gjoni V nuk ishin njerëz të fesë. Për të dy këta, përparësitë politike të bashkimit i kapërcenin problemet c tjera të cilësdo natyrë, ndërsa për teologët çështja nuk ishte kaq e thjeshtë. Që nga kohët e para krishterimi lindor dhe ai perëndimor qenë larguar pak nga pak prej njëri-tjetrit për sa i takonte teologjisë, përdorimit të liturgjisë dhe teorisë e praktikës kishtare. Tashmë ndaheshin për shkak të një problemi madhor teologjik që kishte të bënte me prejardhjen e shpirtit të shenjtë dhe me shtimin nga ana e latinëve të fjalës \emph{filioque} te besorja\footnoteB{Formula e shpalljes së besimit ndër të krishterët. Njihet edhe si kredoja.}. Nuk mungonin edhe çështje të tjera, të dorës së dytë: teoria e energjive, e sapolejuar në Lindje, ishte e papranueshme në Perëndim; dogma perëndimore e purgatorit në sytë e bizantinëve qe vetëm shprehje e një arrogance të pashoqe. Por kontradikta kryesore lidhur me liturgjinë vërtitej rreth naforës së kungimit: duhej gatuar me brumë të ardhur apo jo? Në Lindje mendonin se zakoni perëndimor i naforës me brumë të paardhur i kishte rrënjët te judaizmi dhe tregonte mungesë respekti ndaj shpirtit të shenjtë që simbolizohej edhe nga majaja e bukës. E njëjta mungesë respekti shfaqej edhe në mospranimin nga ana e latinëve të së ashtuquajturës \emph{epiklesis}, thirrja e shpirtit të shenjtë, pa të cilën, sipas lindorëve, buka e 

\newpage

x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\realizueshme\footnote{Për një vështrim përmbledhës të situatës ndërkombëtare shih Gill, \emph{The Council ...}, vep. e cit., ff. 382-383.}. Edhe në oborrin papnor shpresohej e besohej që sulltani i ri nuk çonte peshë në kandar, por këtu refugjatët grekë i frynin zjarrit për një ndërhyrje para se ai t’ua merrte dorën punëve të shtetit. Zëdhënësi i tyre ishte një italian, Françesko Filelfo nga Tolentino. Ky ishte martuar me të bijën e studiuesit bizantin Kryzolaras dhe vjehrra e tij jetonte në Kostandinopojë. Ai i shkroi një thirrje të zjarrtë mbretit Sharl të Francës. Iu drejtua atij ngaqë në të shkuarën Franca ishte vënë në krye të kryqëzatave. E nxiti të ngrinte më këmbë sa më shpejt një ushtri dhe të lëvizte kundër Lindjes, duke i thënë që turqit nuk qenë në gjendje t'i bënin rezistencë. Por mbreti Sharl nuk iu përgjigj\footnote{Letrën e Filelfo-s e risjell Jorga në \emph{Notes et Extraits pour servir à l’Histoire des Croisades}, IV.}. Papa Nikolla V, që pasoi më 1447 Eugjenin IV, ishte një njeri i letrave dhe i paqes, bëma më e madhe e të cilit qe themelimi i Bibliotekës së Vatikanit. Miqësia e tij me Visarionin, kulturën e gjerë të të cilit e çmonte pa masë, e bënte më të ndjeshëm ndaj çështjes greke, por ai nuk dinte se cilit prej laikëve të fuqishëm mund t’i kërkonte ndihmë. Nga ana tjetër, nuk qe i gatshëm t’i vinte vetë në ndihmë një qyteti që nuk pranonte të njëmendësonte bashkimin e nënshkruar në emër të tij nga perandorët e vet në Firence\footnote{Gill, \emph{The Council ...}, vep. e cit., f. 187.}.

Perandori Kostandin e kuptonte më së miri këtë ngërç. Në verën e vitit 1451 ai dërgoi në Perëndim një ambasador, Andronik Brien Leontarisin, i cili fillimisht vajti në Venedik, që t'i siguronte perandorit lejen për të rekrutuar harkëtarë për ushtrinë; ndërsa më pas u kap në Romë me një mesazh miqësor të Kostandinit për papën e me një letër, edhe ajo drejtuar papës, të shkruar prej një komiteti kundërunionistësh. Këta vetëquheshin një \emph{sinas}, meqë termi \emph{sinod} nuk mund të përdorej për një trupë që vepronte pa patriarkun. Perandori i kishte shtyrë vetë ta dërgonin këtë thirrje, pas gjasave i këshilluar nga Llukë Notarasi. Sinasi propozonte të mbahej një koncil i ri, kësaj here në Kostandinopojë. Ky do të ishte vërtet ekumenik, sepse patriarkanat lindore do të përfaqësoheshin të gjitha, ndërsa Romës i kërkohej të dërgonte një

\newpage

x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\x\\garanci për vullnetin e mirë të, sulltanit. Despotit serb, jo vetëm iu kthye vajza, por iu dhanë edhe disa qytete në pjesën e sipërme të luginës së Strumës. Ambasadorët e perandorit Kostandin, të cilët ishin të parët që mbërritën gjithë drojë, ngaqë e njihnin më mirë karakterin e sulltanit të ri, u qetësuan nga mikpritja që iu rezervua. Sulltani u betua mbi Kuran para tyre se do ta respektonte tërësinë territoriale të Bizantit. Ai premtoi që do t’i jepte perandorit një shumë të përvitshme prej tre mijë asprash, nga të ardhurat e disa qyteteve greke të pjesës së poshtme të luginës së Strumës, që ligjërisht i përkisnin një princi otoman, Orhanit. Këto para duhet të përdoreshin për ta mbajtur këtë të fundit të burgosur, ashtu siç ia donte sëra, në Kostandinopojë. Edhe bashkësisë murgjërore të malit Atos, e cila pas pushtimit të Selanikut nga ana e Muratit e kishte njohur mençurisht sovranitetin otoman, iu premtua se nuk do t’i cenohej autonomia\footnote{Dukas, \emph{Historia ...}, vep. e cit., XXXIII, ff. 289-291; Chalkokandyles, \emph{De Origine ...}, vep. e cit., ff. 375-376; Thiriet, \emph{Régestes des déliberations du Sénat de Venise concernant la Romanie}, III, nr. 2862, ff. 167-168; Babinger, \emph{Maometto ...}, vep. e cit., ff. 69-70; Hasluck, \emph{Athos and its Monasteries}, f. 50.}.

Dukej se sulltani i ri ishte nën ndikimin e ministrit të vjetër të Muratit, Halilit, për të cilin dihej se qe njësoj si i zoti, i prirë nga paqja. Diplomatët bizantinë qenë munduar ta mbanin mirë me Halilin dhe kënaqeshin tek shihnin se përpjekjet e tyre po jepnin fryte. Por vëzhgues më të mprehtë do të kishin mundur të vërenin se aktet paqtuese të Mehmetit nuk ishin të sinqerta. Atij i leverdiste të kishte paqe përgjatë kufijve teksa përgatiste fushatën e tij të madhe. Pastaj ndikimi i Halilit mbi sulltanin nuk ishte aq i madh sa mendonin të krishterët. Mehmeti nuk ia pati falur kurrë me të vërtetë rolin frenues që luajti më 1446, ndërsa aleati i tij, Isak pasha, tani ndodhej larg në Anadoll. Saganoz pasha, rivali i tij i vjetër, tashmë nënkryeministër,
\end{document}
```

I hope this vbox is representative of the other 33 I get. There are 100 footnotes or so in the document and no images or graphs at the moment.

Comment: Firstly, the overfull \vbox it complains about is only “0.3491pt too high”. Frankly I wouldn't even worry about such tiny numbers; just set `\vfuzz=1pt` or as large a number as you can tolerate.

Comment: Some go up to 7.2pt; i will try to isolate a better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the latex format documentation in source2e.pdf you will see

```
   \footnoterule   : Macro to draw the rule separating footnotes from
                     text. It is executed right after a \vspace of
                     \skip\footins. It should take zero vertical
                     space--i.e., it should to a negative skip to
                     compensate for any positive space it occupies.
                     (See PLAIN.TEX.)
```

Your definition does not meet this

```
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@
  \vskip 3mm}
```

The two `\kern` are carefully arranged to add up to -.4pt to cancel out the .4pt from the rule, and then it adds 3mm of unwanted space.

perhaps instead:

```
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3mm\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@
  \kern3mm}
```

as long as you know know `\footskip` has big enough minimum size to allow that much backspacing,

Comment: can it be modified to add some minimum space between text and the rule: I will add a separate question.

Comment: @alfred the space between the text and the rule is `\skip\footins - the 3mm backspace you have here so just make skip footins big enough

Answer (score 3):

The overfull vbox occurs because there is nowhere on page 2 for any glue to be shrunk.

You can introduce a little bit of stretchable glue in the space below your footnote rule, which will allow this gap to shrink enough to fit everything on the page.

```
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
  \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@
  \vskip 3mm \@plus 1mm \@minus .5mm}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `vskip mm` with `\vskip 2.8mm` there is no `overfull \vbox`.